# Helper wrapping link_to with an html attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to have a helper that works just like link_to except that it merges in a data attribute (in this case for ease of creating tabs using bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

So I can call it like this:

```
link_to_tab("Name", @obj)
```

and get

```
<a href='/path' data-toggle='tab'>Name</a>
```

I've come up with this which seems to work:

```
def link_to_tab(*args, &block)
  toggle_hash = {'data-toggle' => 'tab'}
  last_arg = args.pop # if link_to was given a hash of html_options, merge with it
  if last_arg.is_a? Hash
    link_to(*args, last_arg.merge(toggle_hash), &block)
  else
    link_to(*args, last_arg, toggle_hash, &block)
  end
end
```

Is there a cleaner, more idiomatic way to support all of the styles of calling link_to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  You could try this...

```
def link_to_tab(*args, &block)
  toggle_hash = {'data-toggle' => 'tab'}
  if args.last.is_a? Hash
    args.last.merge!(toggle_hash) 
  else
    args << toggle_hash
  end
  link_to(*args, &block)
end
```

Not that different though...

Comment: What about calling this with `link_to_tab 'Name', '#'` ? It wouldn't get the attribute in that case. My if/else is to ensure there's a hash passed to link_to, regardless of if one was given.

Comment: Cool, I think your example is better ruby, though not as vastly better as I'd been hoping for. I'm going to leave this open for a little and see if anything else comes along.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to have a helper that works just like link_to except that it merges in a data attribute

I might be missing something, but why not just pass a custom data argument to the link_to helper?

```
= link_to "foo tab", {}, "data-toggle" => "tab"
```

Outputs:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="/">foo tab</a>
```

**Edit**

If you're planning on using it a lot you can do:

```
def link_to_tab(*args, &block)
  if args.last.is_a? Hash
    link_to *(args.take args.size - 1), args.last.merge("data-tab" => "tab"), &block
  else
    link_to *args, "data-tab" => "tab", &block
  end
end
```

Comment: Yea, but then every time I want to add one of these I have to remember that it's the data-toggle attribute, and if things change in the future then I have to go change it everywhere. Seems more DRY to consolidate it into a helper, do you disagree?

Comment: but that won't work if I give link_to a block, or if I pass in a hash as the last option like `link_to 'Name', '/path', class: 'stylish`. I'm looking for the cleanest, most idiomatic way to add my own `link_to_tab` helper that works just like link_to but with this extra attribute.

Comment: Ah, yes. See the updated edit, that aughta enable you to pass however many additional attributes you need and maintain the data-toggle. Can't get much cleaner than that afaik.

Comment: But that doesn't work with a block or when the last arg to link_to is not a hash (`link_to 'Name', '/path'`) :)

Comment: Lol, sometimes it's the simplest things that are the trickiest to do. Well, it isn't quite as succinct but it's an alternative if nothing else, the fact that three people ended up with basically the same answer suggests that there may not be a better way. I think my solution might be a little more agnostic from the template side, assuming it works this time ;) (I swear if it doesn't work for a third time I'm going to have to write some friggin use cases).

Comment: You're still ignoring the block, but I think we're all on roughly the same with this. Thanks for the attempts!